# WCF message security with compression

Tags: wcf, compression, wcf-security, http-compression

**What is the best practice for compressing the communication of a WCF service having message security enabled**, that is not hosted on IIS and uses HTTP as transfer protocol?

In my searching I found implementations made at channel level that apply compression after the message was secured (so the compression is suboptimal).

Can you point me in the right direction?
Or even better: Do you know any WCF compression implementation (working with message security) that is applied before security protocol run?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Sample Compression (Microsoft WCF Samples\WCF\Extensibility\MessageEncoder\Compression) and you can use Message Security as TripleDesSha256 algorithm as this config.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="customNetTcpBinding">
      <transactionFlow transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true"/>
      <Compression innerMessageEncoding="binaryMessageEncoding"
          compressionAlgorithm="GZip" />
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="TripleDesSha256" authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature" messageSecurityVersion="Default" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true" requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
        <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="true" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite" replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="false" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00" maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="false" maxPendingSessions="128" maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
        <secureConversationBootstrap defaultAlgorithmSuite="TripleDesSha256" authenticationMode="SspiNegotiated" requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature" messageSecurityVersion="Default" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true" requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
          <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="true" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite" replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
          <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" issuedCookieLifetime="00:15:00" maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128" maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
        </secureConversationBootstrap>
      </security>
      <tcpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" connectionBufferSize="8192" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" channelInitializationTimeout="00:00:05" maxBufferSize="65536" maxPendingConnections="10" maxOutputDelay="00:00:00.2000000" maxPendingAccepts="1" transferMode="Buffered" listenBacklog="10" portSharingEnabled="false" teredoEnabled="false">
        <connectionPoolSettings groupName="default" leaseTimeout="00:05:00" idleTimeout="00:02:00" maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="10" />
      </tcpTransport>          
    </binding>      
  </customBinding>
```